# What are some more examples of doubly centre embedded clauses?

Tags: grammar, psycholinguistics, clauses, production

Hey guys I am a uni student doing psycholinguistics and currently studying doubly centre embedded clauses for a study on comprehension.

For example a phrase such as: "The man the boy the cat scratched kicked died."

These sentences are notoriously hard to parse, even though they're grammatical,  and  I need a list of them for a study I'm designing, I'd be grateful for any more examples of such phrases, and for them  to not be too similar  to each other.

Any help  is appreciated, Thanks !

Comment: _The horse the guy my brother knew bought had glanders._ They're easy to make up, Since you're doing psycholinguistics you can figure out the rules, I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Yes they are easy to make up however since I need to think of quite a few, the difficulty lies in making sure all the examples are semantically plausible (which is the hard part for me), thanks again !